# Apk android with signature scheme v2

Tags: apk, signature-error

Is it possible to unpack an application and re-pack it with changes and make it work on Android 11?

I unpacked and recompiled an app without making any changes. I later signed it following this [guide](https://liapp.lockincomp.com/blog/blog-Post/%E2%80%A6), but when i try to install it with adb, I obtain this error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2 –

I read that on Android 11 you have to sign the apk with schema v2. I did it but the app gives me an error when I try to install it.

Comment: Hi robert, my app can be installed on devices that have at least android 11 installed. I unpacked and recompiled it without making any changes. I later signed it following this guide: https://liapp.lockincomp.com/blog/blog-Post/tech-apk-signature-scheme-v2-with-apksigner/ but when i try to install it with adb, I obtain this error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2

Comment: When zipping the APK I would change the compression method to "store" (no compression). That should be the safest option to avoid problems. In some cases it may also be necessary to apply `zipalign` on the APK before signing.

Comment: that is, when do I repack the application with apktool? could you tell me the command you mean?

Comment: `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK Failed to extract native libraries,` has nothing to do with APK signature v2. Please concentrate on one question. At the moment your question seems to be more like "how to repack an APK correctly". If you really want to ask that please edit your question and write it that way.

Comment: I found this solution on the net: delete this tag from the manifest from the manifest --> android:extractNativeLibs="false" I deleted it and repackaged the application with the simple b command from apktool. Later  i signed the application with jarsigner. I tried to install it with adb and now I get this error: Failure [-124: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Targeting R+ (version 30 and above) requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary]. What should I do in your opinion?

Comment: The the message indicates you need to execute zipalign on the apk before signing.